# Trouble viewing rows not affected from UPDATE using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update some 600+ rows of customer data, using a query I've generated from Excel. I'm generating my update query using data that is more recent than the data we have in our test environment - so I want to view the rows that were **not updated** when I finish executing within the test environment.

I am trying to achieve this with `IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1`.

Consider the following update query:

```
CREATE TABLE #not_updated (
  NOT_UPDATED VARCHAR(30)
);

UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL1 = 'text1A' WHERE COL2 LIKE 'text1B'; IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1 INSERT INTO #not_updated SELECT 'text1B'
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL1 = 'text2A' WHERE COL2 LIKE 'text2B'; IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1 INSERT INTO #not_updated SELECT 'text2B'
--            |
--            V
-- 600+ MORE INSERTS...

SELECT * FROM #not_updated

DROP TABLE #temp
```

However, when I run the query, `SELECT * FROM #not_updated` it does not return any rows - *even though I can see in the "Messages" tab* `0 rows affected` *for some of the entries.*

If I change my code to `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1`, my select will return that entry. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Or if there is an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: You're inserting into `#not_updated` and selecting from `#not_inserted`

Comment: @cf_en whoops, typo in my question. Would've seen the error if I tried to execute that in SSMS

Comment: I suppose I could fix this by just checking if a SELECT returns >0 rows for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the reliability of `@@ROWCOUNT` when UPDATE fails (entry does not exist). For now, I'm using the following workaround:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL1 = 'text1A' WHERE COL2 LIKE 'text1B'; IF (SELECT COUNT(*) TABLE1 WHERE COL2 LIKE 'text1B') < 1 INSERT INTO #not_updated SELECT 'text1B'
```

Comment: I tested what you were trying to do in the question and had no issues, and I can't see why yours isn't working if it's fully representative of the code you're actually running (hence I couldn't post an answer). Your workaround could be written as an `IF NOT EXISTS...` rather than a `COUNT(*)... < 1`. It should be more efficient when a match is found, as it can stop looking when it finds one match instead of counting how many rows do match.